# QuickBlox integration causes exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-runtime, quickblox

I could not find any good material for QuickBlox integration. I am coding for metro app and following official docs. that's written for WP7 but somewhere I also read its equivalent to windows 8.
Following is the code and error!

```
private const int AppID = 150;
private const int OwnerID = 4331;
private const string AuthKey = "8vXrOPEEXFacuEa";
private const string AuthSecret = "Up3AjdkjEDAzraL";

public QuickBloxSDK_Silverlight.QuickBlox QBlox
{ get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
     // QBlox is receive null and cause for exception
     this.QBlox = new QuickBloxSDK_Silverlight.QuickBlox(AppID, OwnerID,   AuthKey, AuthSecret);
     InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies wp7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBlox doesn't support WP SDK yet

It's open sourced now, check it here https://github.com/QuickBlox/SDK-wp7

You can use it as is and try to port to Windows 8